# A question about the find function of Google dense_hash_map

Tags: c++, hashmap

I use Google’s dense_hash_map as a cache of some data. When I use the find function to find a key, I find that it doesn’t exist, but when traversing dense_hash_map, I can see that the key exists. Is it wrong where I used it? By the way, I have rewritten the EqualKey class required by dense_hash_map.

This is my test code:

```cpp
class StringVal {
  public:
  StringVal(string &str) {
    len = str.length();
    ptr = new uint8_t[len];
    memcpy(ptr, str.c_str(), len);
  }

  StringVal(uint8_t* ptr = NULL, int len = 0) : len(len), ptr(ptr) {
    if(ptr == NULL) {
      is_null = NULL;
    }
  }

  StringVal(const char* ptr) : len(strlen(ptr)),ptr(const_cast<uint8_t*>(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(ptr))) {
    if(ptr == NULL) {
      is_null = NULL;
    }
  }

  ~StringVal() {
    delete[] ptr;
  }

  uint8_t* ptr;
  int len;
  bool is_null;

  static StringVal null() {
    StringVal sv;
    sv.is_null = true;
    return sv;
  }

  bool operator==(const StringVal& other) const {
    if (is_null != other.is_null) return false;
    if (is_null) return true;
    if (len != other.len) return false;
    return ptr == other.ptr || memcmp(ptr, other.ptr, len) == 0;
  }

  bool operator!=(const StringVal& other) const { return !(*this == other); }
};

struct NewStringValCmp {
  bool operator()(const StringVal* s1, const StringVal* s2) const {
    if (s1 == NULL && s2 == NULL) return 1;
    if (s1 == NULL || s2 == NULL) return 0;

    if (s1->is_null != s2->is_null) return false;
    if (s1->is_null) return true;
    if (s1->len != s2->len) return false;
    return memcmp(s1->ptr, s2->ptr, s1->len) == 0;
  }
};

typedef dense_hash_map<StringVal*, StringVal*, std::hash<StringVal*>, NewStringValCmp> new_dict_map_string_t;

vector<string> data = {
  "test1","1",
  "test2","2",
  "test3","3",
  "test4","4",
  "test5","5",
  "test6","6",
  "test7","7",
  "test8","8",
  "test9","9",
  "test10","10"
};

int main() {
  new_dict_map_string_t* cm = new new_dict_map_string_t();
  cm->set_empty_key(NULL);

  for (int i = 0; (i + 1) < data.size(); i+=2) {
    StringVal *key = new StringVal(data[i]);
    StringVal *value = new StringVal(data[i+1]);
    (*cm)[key] = value;
  }
  
  string input = "";
  while (1) {
    cin >> input;
    if (input == "q") {
      break;
    }

    StringVal *target = new StringVal(input);

    for (auto itor: *cm) {
      if (*(itor.first) == *target) {
        cout << "find target" << endl;
      }
    }

    auto itor = cm->find(target);
    if (itor == cm->end()) {
      cout << "cm->find nothing" << endl;
    } else {
      cout << itor->second->ptr << endl;
    }
    delete target;

    input = "";
  }
  
  for (auto iter : *cm) {
    delete iter.first;
    delete iter.second;
  }
  
  delete cm;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your code in the question. Without the code we cannot possibly tell if you made something wrong in your code

Comment: I added a reproducible test code, can you help me

Comment: no I can't, but if you explain what the code is supposed to do and what it does instead then I am certain that someone else can

Comment: Also read [mre]. For the question you first asked I would have expected only a couple of lines of code. Is really all of the code relevant to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I know why it doesn’t work anymore. I didn’t rewrite the hash function. Thank you anyway.